# Which algorithm for controlling cars on a race track?

Tags: path-finding

I think A* is a good place to start, but since cars cannot move in all directions (they move like cars do, trying to move forward and steer), I was wondering if someone could point me at other approaches they've used.

Also, I was wondering about the "Racing Line". Should one just precompute the optimal paths, and then use the A* to select the path that isn't blocked by other cars ?

EDIT: My question is different from [Driver AI in racing game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141265/driver-ai-in-racing-game) because that question is about approaches.

I am interested in learning about specific tried and trusted algorithms like A*.

Comment: Is this for the AI to control the cars? I'm not sure if A* would be applicable, because it assumes an object can move in all directions without an issue, depending how your cars work, this might need a lot of tweaking, or not be possible in an optimal way.

Comment: You can change A* to take into account the speed and steering options. But you are going to end up with a near optimal racing line if you do so (at least without other cars to collide with)

Comment: We have some past Q&A about algorithms for racing game AI, which I've linked above. Please take a read. If these existing answers don't solve your problem, or you have trouble implementing them, please edit your question to detail the specific issue you need to overcome/improve, and we can re-open it for answers.

Comment: @DMGregory Which is the appropriate tag for game ai algorithms in general? Is there one ? It seems like if you don't know the actual algorithm name its hard to ask or look up the algorithm in the first place.

Comment: @DMGregory That question doesn't actually provide an answer about algorithms, but rather about approaches

Comment: Honestly, I'll usually just [use a search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=racing+game+ai) rather than limiting the search to a single tag. As for "approaches vs algorithms," you did literally ask "I was wondering if someone could point me at other approaches" ;) What you need here is a way to solve the problem, which you can find at these two links. Very often good racing AI won't be a simple CS algorithm like A*, so don't get hung up on finding answers in exactly that style. You"ll learn more from researching how folks actually solve this in games than by requiring they fit that mold.

Comment: I did literally ask "Which ALGORITHM for controlling cars on a race track ?".. gosh wonder how anyone could miss that... :D Thanks for the search engine recommendation! I would never have thought of that, nor have I used one before....haha.. yeah, I certainly wouldn't have learned about neural networks on colin mcraes rally either...yeah I certainly should research how folks actually solve this in games...